# Making a class to provide Lists interface

Tags: c++, list, class

Im trying to make a class to use in a Library, and im not sure if its even possible to do. The idea of this class, is to provide methods to insert, search and delete items on a list, but my main problem is that, as i dont know the type of object that i want to place in a list, I dont know how to work with it. I thought I could place a void pointer, and then make it point to a structure, but I havent been able to make it work.

Lets suppose my class is something like this:

```
class ListManager
{
    private:
         void* FirstItem;//This would point to the first item of the list
         void* LastItem;//This would point to the last item of the list
    public:
         void AddItemToList(void* Item);
         void RemoveItemFromList(void* Item);
}
```

So, the idea would be that, from my program, I can define a structure like

```
struct Employee
{
    *char Name;
    int Id;
    int PhoneNumber;
}
```

And then, use this class, to be able to add/delete Employees. So in this case, the void* pointers, should be pointing to a struct of the type Employee. Nevertheless, i want to make my class work for any type of struct.
I dont know if i explained exactly what I want to do, I tried several ways of doing this, and failed on all of them.

Im going to post a code of how I would like the class to work, if I havent explained myself correctly

```
ListManager *Worker;
Worker=new(ListManager);

Employee *Item;
Item=new (Employee);

Item->Id=126;
Item->PhoneNumber=42154872;

Worker->AddItemToList(Item);
/*At this point, FirstItem and LastItem should point to the Item i just created*/
```

Could someone point me in the right direction, as how to make a class work with a structure, without knowing the type of structure?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you looked into template classes?

Comment: templates is probably what you are looking for. You would make a templated class with template parameter `T` and instead of using `void*` you could use the correct type (i.e. `T`)

Comment: templates indeed. Also, try to avoid all those new.
ListManager *Worker; 
becomes: ListManager worker; and so on

Comment: Why not simply use the excelent [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), or [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/)?

Comment: use a `map` or `vector`. and create a class for it if you want to hide the imlementation details.

Comment: Consulting the things you've most recently learned from your book or teacher should provide very good clues.

Comment: If you want an idea how std::list is implemented take a look at [libstd++ list implementaition](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01509_source.html):

Comment: I havent thought of Templates, I was trying a far more complicated approach, im going to give it a try, thx for the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need templates! 
here's a simple interface that you can start working with.

```
template <typename T>
class ListManager
{
    public:
         void addItemToList(const T& item);
         void removeItemFromList(const T& item);
}
```

Now T is your type, and you'd declare a ListManager like this:

```
ListManager<Employee> manager;
```

I would suggest you also to look at the stl documentation/implementation of a list at: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/
You have also the concept of iterators to dig into. 
Also, try to use values instead of pointers. With the interface I gave you, you would store the actual value in the list and not a pointer, so the list owns the object and you won't need to manage your memory manually.

Answer (score 0):

See this Tutorial:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_templates.htm

Your Example could be look like:

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class ListManager
{
    private:
         void* FirstItem;//This would point to the first item of the list
         void* LastItem;//This would point to the last item of the list
    public:
         void AddItemToList(const T& Item){
            std::cout << Item << std::endl;
         };
         void RemoveItemFromList(const T& Item){};
};

int main() {
    ListManager<std::string> mgr;
    mgr.AddItemToList("Test");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test
```

Working Example:
http://ideone.com/FCAtcJ

Answer (score 0):

There really are no interfaces in C++, but you could use a class template just the same way:

```
template <typename T>
class ListInterface {
public:
  void add(T * item) { list.push_back( item); }
  void remove(T * item) { list.erase(std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), item)); }
  T * get(int index) { return list[index]; }
  int size() const { return list.size(); }
private:
  std::vector<T *> list;
};

class Manager : public ListInterface<Employee> {
  // ...
};
```

Naturally, this is a barebone example, you really outta do some checking in the `remove()` and `get()` methods.

Comment: "There really are no interfaces in C++" ..isnt a pure abstract class without data members an interface by definition?

Comment: My point is it is still a class, there is no `interface` keywords like in say Java.

Comment: Sorry for splitting hairs, but there is also no `abstract` keyword for example, but there are definitely abstract classes in C++ (of course they are also "just classes", but it completely makes sense to name them for what they are)

Comment: There is no `abstract` keyword, but there is `T foo() = 0` which is C++'s `abstract` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple solutions to this problem.

Simply use std::list

```
std::list<Employee> manager;
```

If 1. is not possible you can define your own list interface using template

```
template <class T>
class ListManager
{
private:
     class Iterator {
     public:
          T& item;
          Iterator* next;
          Iterator* prev;
          Iterator(T& i, Iterator* n, Iterator* p) : item(i), next(n), prev(p) {}
     }
     Iterator* FirstItem = NULL;//This would point to the first item of the list
     Iterator* LastItem = NULL;//This would point to the last item of the list
public:
     void AddItemToList(T& Item) {
           if(LastItem) {
                 Iterator* it = new Iterator{Item, NULL, LastItem};
                 LastItem->next = it;
                 LastItem = it;
           } else {
                 Iterator* it = new Iterator{Item, NULL, NULL};
                 FirstItem = it;
                 LastItem = it;
           }
     }
     void RemoveItemFromList(const T& Item) { 
         for(Iterator* it = FirstItem; it != NULL; it = it->next) {
               if(it->item == Item) {
                    if(it->prev)
                         it->prev->next = it->next;
                    else
                         FirstItem = it->next;
                    if(it->next)
                         it->next->pref = it->pref;
                    else
                         LastItem = it->pref;
                    delete it;
                    break;
               }
         }
     }
};
```

If 1. and 2. is not possible because you need need multiple types inside your list. You can either use a list of Anys (like [boost::Any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/any.html)) or a unsafe version with `void*`:

```
class ListManager
{
private:
     class Iterator {
     public:
          void* item;
          Iterator* next;
          Iterator* prev;
          Iterator(void* i, Iterator* n, Iterator* p) : item(i), next(n), prev(p) {}
     }
     Iterator* FirstItem = NULL;//This would point to the first item of the list
     Iterator* LastItem = NULL;//This would point to the last item of the list
public:
     template<class T>
     void AddItemToList(T& Item) {
           if(LastItem) {
                 Iterator* it = new Iterator{&Item, NULL, LastItem};
                 LastItem->next = it;
                 LastItem = it;
           } else {
                 Iterator* it = new Iterator{&Item, NULL, NULL};
                 FirstItem = it;
                 LastItem = it;
           }
     }
     template<class T>
     void RemoveItemFromList(const T& Item) { 
         for(Iterator* it = FirstItem; it != NULL; it = it->next) {
               if(it->item == &Item) {
                    if(it->prev)
                         it->prev->next = it->next;
                    else
                         FirstItem = it->next;
                    if(it->next)
                         it->next->pref = it->pref;
                    else
                         LastItem = it->pref;
                    delete it;
                    break;
               }
         }
     }
};
```

Code is not tested